# Como implementar o arrastar e soltar em uma página html?

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

Sou programador Delphi, mas gostaria de implementar uma página html com a função de arrastar e soltar um elemento da pagina.

Estou criando uma página para montagem de avatar, mas gostaria de deixar as opções dos acessórios para o usuário somente arrastar e soltar.

Tentei implementar usando html/css/jquery. Existe uma forma simples ou um exemplo claro de fazer isso ?

Comment: Você já fez alguma coisa?

Comment: Acho que encontrei o que quero nesse link aqui https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Comece pelo jQuery UI Sortable Plugin](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/). Ele faz exatamente o que você quer.

Exemplo funcional:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Sortable - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  #sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; }
  #sortable li { margin: 0 3px 3px 3px; padding: 0.4em; padding-left: 1.5em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; }
  #sortable li span { position: absolute; margin-left: -1.3em; }
  </style>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<ul id="sortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 5</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 6</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 7</li>
</ul>


</body>
</html>
```

Ou ainda o [jQuery UI Draggable Plugin](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/).